# How to get position of text in an image using Mobile Vision API?

Tags: android, xamarin, imageview, text-recognition, vision-api

How to get the position of text on the screen in an image using Mobile Vision API, and how to draw a rectangle around them?

Example:

[image]

Comment: In the returned `Text` you can pull the components and that include the "bounding boxes", Google has a CodeLab with this exact example, just need to translate it to C#  https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/mobile-vision-ocr/#6

Comment: ok will check now.

Comment: GraphicOverlay is a class in the sample, it just extends View  (via the GraphicOverlay.Graphic abstract class), I believe, been awhile since I referenced it to use Mobile Vision in Xamarin (FYI: If this is new code that you are writing, you might want to look at "ML Kit" as it has replaced the Mobile Vision APIs from Google)

Comment: ok i will get TextBlock info by  
getBoundingBox() method, will the below code work just by implementing in c# public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
   
    if (text == null) {
        return;
    }

    
    RectF rect = new RectF(text.getBoundingBox());
    rect = translateRect(rect);
    canvas.drawRect(rect, rectPaint);

Comment: and that ML Kit is specially for android studio developers i think, and Mobile vision API is free as far as i know

Comment: ML.Kit on device processing is "free" just like M.Vision, the higher accuracy cloud services, like the OCR/Text recognizers, are a billed Firebase service as they are not limited to the mobile optimized ML models and the Android/iOS APIs work fine w/ Xamarin.

Comment: Does it have c# libraries ?

Comment: I got three versions can u say which is free version https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/detecting-text#vision-text-detection-java , https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/android/recognize-text ,https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/mobile-vision-ocr/#0

Comment: Under ML Kit : https://firebase.google.com/pricing/

Comment: so confusing lol. anyway, as long as I use to detect anything that is on the local device it is free? (no free access to cloud version anyway i think )

Comment: ML.Kit : Local = free, Cloud = $

Comment: ya but i cannot see c# implementation of it, can u look at this page an say if it is ML Kit version or not https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/detecting-text

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**How to do it**

Put an `ImageView` in the layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250.0dp"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:id="@+id/imageView1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Instantiate `ImageView` in `onCreate` Method

```
ImageView imgView;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

        imgView = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView1);
        OCR();
    }
```

**THIS IS IMPORTANT CODE FOR GETTING TEXT AND DRAWING RECTANGLE ON IT**

*Please read Comments on top of code*

```
public void OCR()
    {
        //Convert The Image To Bitmap
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(ApplicationContext.Resources, Resource.Mipmap.lineindent);

        TextRecognizer textRecognizer = new TextRecognizer.Builder(ApplicationContext).Build();

        if (!textRecognizer.IsOperational)
        {

            Log.Error("Main Activity", "Dependencies not available");

            // Check android for low storage so dependencies can be loaded, DEPRICATED CHANGE LATER
            IntentFilter intentLowStorage = new IntentFilter(Intent.ActionDeviceStorageLow);

            bool hasLowStorage = RegisterReceiver(null, intentLowStorage) != null;

            if (hasLowStorage)
            {

                Toast.MakeText(this, "Low Memory On Disk", ToastLength.Long);
                Log.Error("Main Activity", "Low Memory On Disk");
            }

        }
        else
        {
            Frame frame = new Frame.Builder().SetBitmap(bitmap).Build();


            SparseArray items = textRecognizer.Detect(frame);
            List<TextBlock> blocks = new List<TextBlock>();

            TextBlock myItem = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < items.Size(); ++i)
            {
                myItem = (TextBlock)items.ValueAt(i);

                //Add All TextBlocks to the `blocks` List
                blocks.Add(myItem);

            }
            //END OF DETECTING TEXT

            //The Color of the Rectangle to Draw on top of Text
            Paint rectPaint = new Paint();
            rectPaint.Color = Color.White;
            rectPaint.SetStyle(Paint.Style.Stroke);
            rectPaint.StrokeWidth = (4.0f);

            //Create the Canvas object,
            //Which ever way you do image that is ScreenShot for example, you 
            //need the views Height and Width to draw recatngles 
            //because the API detects the position of Text on the View
            //So Dimesnions are important for Draw method to draw at that Text 
            //Location
            Bitmap tempBitmap = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height, Bitmap.Config.Rgb565);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(tempBitmap);
            canvas.DrawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);

            //Loop through each `Block`
            foreach (TextBlock textBlock in blocks)
            {
                IList<IText> textLines = textBlock.Components; 

                //loop Through each `Line`
                foreach (IText currentLine in textLines)
                {
                    IList<IText>  words = currentLine.Components;

                    //Loop through each `Word`
                    foreach (IText currentword in words)
                    {
                        //Get the Rectangle/boundingBox of the word
                        RectF rect = new RectF(currentword.BoundingBox);
                        rectPaint.Color = Color.Black;

                        //Finally Draw Rectangle/boundingBox around word
                        canvas.DrawRect(rect, rectPaint);

                        //Set image to the `View`
                        imgView.SetImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(Resources, tempBitmap));


                    }

                }
            }

        }
    }
```

***RESULT***

[image]

If you want the Rectangle on `Lines` then remove the code from `words` loops and put it in the `Lines` loop, same goes to the blocks

[image]