# How to get position of a text inside an image and highlight it when image is touched at it's position

Tags: java, android, kotlin, google-vision

In my app i'm having an activity which is having an imageview there i'm basically setting a bitmap into it  now here i'm using google vision library to fetch text from images in I've succeeded in that however **tricky part is** that when imageview is clicked at particular position if it contains any text I want it to get highlighted and again if same is clicked I want to be unhighlighted it's kind of select and unselect effect i tried referring many answers but all of them seem to highlight all texts at runtime but I want only a particular to be highlighted when clicked at that position I guess for that I will need to get text position from images and compare it with touch event but I can't seem to find a way to do it here's my code which i'm using to get text from image:

```
copyimg.setImageBitmap(ImageCaptureActivity.mbitmap)
      val textRecognizer = TextRecognizer.Builder(applicationContext).build()

        val imageFrame = Frame.Builder()

            .setBitmap(ImageCaptureActivity.mbitmap)                 // your image bitmap
            .build()

        var imageText = ""


        val textBlocks = textRecognizer.detect(imageFrame)

        for (i in 0 until textBlocks.size()) {
            val textBlock = textBlocks.get(textBlocks.keyAt(i))
            imageText = textBlock.value                   // return string
            Log.i("Okaycheckthis:", imageText)
        }
```

Here's an screenshot of what i'm trying to implement:
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: It's called OCR , someone have already answered a similar question that can help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/53761790/8399299

Comment: I've already tried that but i want to select text on touch event of imageview

Comment: @R.Coder I  was looking for a similar use case but in my case, I want to use static text pages instead. were you able to fine any solution rather than using OCR?